# How to access web server from multiple devices by name instead of IP?

Tags: networking, dns, ip, android, xampp

I have a php site running on a local XAMPP web server.  I would like to be able to access the site from multiple devices (other desktops, laptops, iPad and Android tablets) running on the same LAN by using a name/alias (e.g. myapp.local) instead of by IP address.

Using hostname works but only on the Windows devices because of netbios name resolution but I can't use hostname on the iPad or Android devices.

My searching so far seems to suggest I have to setup my own DNS server.  I've tried doing this with MaraDNS following the instructions [here](http://blog.mixu.net/2009/10/14/how-to-setup-a-lan-dns-server-using-maradns-%20%20under-windows-7/) but I need something where I don't have to modify the router settings.

I only want to install stuff on the computer hosting the web server and not edit host files or anything like that.  Is there anyway to do this in as simple a way as possible so on any computer/device I can enter something like myapp.local and it resolves correctly?

Comment: Looks like you should consider a service like dyndns. [Here's](http://www.makeuseof.com/tag/connect-home-network-dyndns) a guide.

Answer (score 0):

I don't have a good answer on how to do it without dhcpd/dns but since I can't comment I'll point you into the zeroconf direction, also zeroconf with mDns.

Personally I went with a home server and setup bind and dhcpd.

My router is a fritz box. I turned off FB's dhcpd so I could set the nameserver by dhcpd.

dhcp.conf

```
# option definitions common to all supported networks...
option domain-name "fritz.box";
option domain-name-servers 192.168.178.2;
default-lease-time 864000;
max-lease-time 1123200;
authoritative;
log-facility local7;
subnet 192.168.178.0 netmask 255.255.255.0 {
  range 192.168.178.21 192.168.178.100;
  option routers 192.168.178.1;
  option subnet-mask 255.255.255.0;
  option broadcast-address 192.168.178.255;
  option ntp-servers 192.168.178.1;
}
```

192.168.178.2 is my homeserver
192.168.178.1 is my router
my router also has a ntp server running

as for bind, this is what a wildcard tld zone config looks like
pri/server.zone

```
$ORIGIN .
$TTL 3600
server  IN SOA server.fritz.box. hostmaster.localhost. (
                3 ; serial
                3600 ; refresh
                3600 ; retry
                604800 ; expire
                86400 ; minimum
)
        NS 192.168.178.2
        IN MX 100 server.
$TTL 86400
$ORIGIN server.
@       IN A 192.168.178.2
*       IN A 192.168.178.2
@       IN AAAA xxxx:xxxx:xxxx:xxxx::2
*       IN AAAA xxxx:xxxx:xxxx:xxxx::2
```

and the named.conf entry

```
zone "server" IN {
        type master;
        file "pri/server.zone";
        notify no;
};
```